# correct comma usage with lists

Tags: sentence-construction, commas

1. All content is copyright to the their respective owners, the webmasters claim no ownership and receive no financial gain for this site
2. This police officer is truly deserving of this award, *he had dedicated his life to service the service of others, and he continues to do good work.*

What is the difference between 1 & 2 in-terms of a comma-splice?

And how does 2 differ from this last example which is correct ?

3. He deserved the award, he worked for it, and he should be proud of it.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentence is an example of a comma splice. If *and*, or another conjunction, were used instead of the comma (or, stylistically, possibly along with it), it would no longer be a comma splice. Alternatively, of course, you could use a semicolon, period, or dash instead of a comma, negating the need for a conjunction at all.

Both the second and third sentences give three items that are separated by a comma, with *and* being used after the second comma. This is correct usage.

---

However, while not being an example of a comma splice, the second sentence does have a couple of stylistic issue:

- *To service the service of others* is strange phrasing, and would normally be rewritten as ***in the service*** *of others*.
- *The difference in tenses between the three items is unusual. Although it may be that he has since stopped dedicating his life to others, it looks odd to jump from present to past to present. Ideally, it should be rephrased to prevent that. However, that's not a comma splice issue.